# How to split up the value as an array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How to split up the value to an array. I have the whmcs api data it looks like 1,2,3,4,5. I need to split up the value to an array value suggest any solution

**My api data**

```
Array
(
[result] => success
[totalresults] => 2
[promotions] => Array
    (
        [promotion] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 6
                        [code] => 0UP3NU5J7J
                        [type] => Percentage
                        [recurring] => 0
                        [value] => 15.00
                        [cycles] => One Time,Monthly,Quarterly,Semi-Annually,Annually,Biennially,Triennially,1Years
                        [appliesto] => 1,2,3
                        [requires] => 1,2,3
                        [requiresexisting] => 0
                        [startdate] => 2018-10-22
                        [expirationdate] => 2018-10-25
                        [maxuses] => 0
                        [uses] => 0
                        [lifetimepromo] => 0
                        [applyonce] => 0
                        [newsignups] => 0
                        [existingclient] => 0
                        [onceperclient] => 0
                        [recurfor] => 0
                        [upgrades] => 0
                        [upgradeconfig] => a:4:{s:5:"value";s:4:"0.00";s:4:"type";s:0:"";s:12:"discounttype";s:10:"Percentage";s:13:"configoptions";s:0:"";}
                        [notes] => 
                    )
     )
  )
)
```

**My code is**

```
   @foreach($response['promotions']['promotion'][0] as $key => $value)
     @if($key == 'appliesto')
            {{$var=$value}}
     @endif
  @endforeach
```

I need to split the "appliesto" value as an array.Please suggest any solution

Comment: use the `explode` function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Also, you shouldn't place logic like that into the template. The much cleaner approach would be to have a Promotion object that holds the data, with methods such as `getCycles() :array`, ie methods that will return the value in the required form to make things more structured and reusable.

Answer (score 2):

just use the explode function like :

```
$apelistoArray = explode(',',$value);
```

This will return an array of the values that the *appliesto* field has so you need to parse them as an array.

This new array has to be parsed inside a loop before you use the curly brackets to echo the values in the blade.

So you have to do something like below:

```
@foreach($apelistoArray as $data)
{{$data}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

No need of loop:-

```
$response['promotions']['promotion'][0]['appliesto'] = explode(',',$response['promotions']['promotion'][0]['appliesto']);
```

But if `promotions` can have multiple child array then do:-

```
@foreach($response['promotions']['promotion'] as &$value)
   $value['appliesto'] = explode(',',$value['appliesto']);
@endforeach
```

Reference:- [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: @foreach($response['promotions']['promotion'] as $value)
     $value['appliesto'] = explode(',',$value['appliesto']);
  {{$value['appliesto']}}
  @endforeach   will you please suggest what i made a mistake

Comment: Based on what you do there `$value['appliesto']` is an array and you try to echo it as a string. You should parse it before you use the {{ }}, those are for echoing a string

Comment: will you please suggest or send any example

Comment: @sharmila  I am unable to understand what you finally trying to do?do you want to show `appliesto` all values one-by-one on your view?